# How to add myself back into sudoers in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, administrator, sudo, sudoers

I have just updated the software, which included replacing the sudoers file. 
Having noted the line in the file for myself, I expected to be able to edit it and put myself back.

I was wrong - it removed my `sudo` permissions, so I locked myself out.

How can I fix this problem?

I do have terminal access.

Comment: My version of nginx is wheezy which has that vulnerability fixed. Its also a VPS, so I can't boot off Live CD, but my ISP might help.

Answer (score 3):

Do you know your `root` password? If yes, than just login using `root` account and fix this issue. Also you could boot single-mode and fix this issue.

If it doesn't work, then other options available. Do you have `nginx` installed? If yes, there is [vulnerability](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2016-1247) in nginx package at Ubuntu/Debian that will allow you to get root permissions.

No `nginx`? No problem, I guess you have some other packages installed which have vulnerabilities that could give your root permissions.
If nothing helps then boot your server from any LiveCD/LiveUSB, mount your original root partition and fix `sudoers` file.

Comment: @Ian may be you have `root` access? May be you know `root` password and can login on terminal or have `root` ssh key and you could try `ssh -l root <server>` ? This will be the easiest soultion. Also there are some alternatives to `sudo` like `super` installed even you don't know about that. Try commands from https://www.sudo.ws/other.html, may be you will be lucky. Also check google for "<Your vps provider> single mode" -- people often needs `single mode` for a lot of reasons and your VPS provider may have option to access it.

Comment: @Ian also if your VPS supports `cloud-init` you could add more section to your vps' user-data clod-init configuration, reboot your server from Panel/Dashboard and have your `sudoers` fixed.